# GGTS IDE complains unable to resolve plugin classes but the application compiles and runs without issues

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, ggts, grails-3.0.9

GGTS IDE complains `unable to resolve plugin classes` when importing but the application compiles and runs without issues. Could someone please help resolve this error

e.g. : When using grails jms plugin and defining the Queue annotation

import grails.plugin.jms.Queue
 @Queue(name='msg.new')

The error thrown by IDE is Groovy:

> unable to resolve class grails.plugin.jms.Queue

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vahidhedayati/68d0133ec19e343e7b80

Comment: Tried all the commands mentioned in the post but it is not working. I am working with grails 3.0.8 and when we import this project in GGTS it is a gradle project and not grails project. Most of the commands in the post either fail with error "this project is not grails project" or command not available.

Comment: Grails 3.0.8? Ggts?  Grails 2 for Ggts and 3 should really be intelij community edition.